# How can i create such kind of product with custom properties in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

[image]

How can I add this kind of custom attributes in magento product? I had tried it with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

create a bundle product through admin panel. go to catalog -> manage products. click on add product. there you have to specify the product as bundle product. add the drop down options, anything you need to add to the product in the bundle item section